# Problems with appcompat_v7 and values-v21

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I recently downloaded eclipse + Android SDK + ADT Plugin and when I create an Android Application Project, the appcompat_v7 project had an error in the res/values-v21 folder and a red exclamation mark next to a new project I created (is named "Test"). After searching over other questions, **I updated the SDK target to 21 in project.properties in appcompat_v7 project**. 
However, when I created a new project appeared an error that said "duplicated jar files".
I kept trying to delete the "android v4 support jar" and adding the appcompat_v7 .jar file and didn't work. Now I got a problem, it seems that there's no errors in the "Test" project (as shown [here](http://i1176.photobucket.com/albums/x332/JMShoujo/Captura2.png)) but eclipse doesn't allow me to create activities inside the project. **I already updated the ADT plugin in eclipse --> Help --> Install new software, etc. and already cleaned both projects** 
If anybody could help me I'd be really grateful, I don't know what to do and I'm despeared.

Answer (score 0):

This error tends to appear when the libs/jar file in the project and library are different. Copy the jar file from one of them and paste it into the other.